# Spring JPA find by method is getting SQL statement error

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a API for a dining review. I am using spring MVC method and trying to add a user to my database using a post method at the url of http://localhost:8080/user/add . I am able to connect to my spring app and I see that everything is working as expected until my application attempts to run the findByUsername method I've created in my repo.
Here is my model class

```
package com.dining.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private boolean peanutAll;
    private boolean eggAll;
    private boolean dairyAll;
    

    
    
}
```

Controller

```
package com.dining.controller;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.dining.exceptions.UserAlreadyExistsException;
import com.dining.model.User;
import com.dining.service.UserService;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@RestController

@RequestMapping(path="/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired UserService userv;
    @Autowired User returnUser;
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user){
        System.out.print(user.getUsername());
    Optional<User> tempUser =   userv.getUser(user.getUsername());
    if(tempUser.isEmpty()) {
        returnUser = userv.addUser(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(returnUser);
    }
    else {
        throw new UserAlreadyExistsException(String.format("User %s already exists", user.getUsername()));
    }

    }
}
```

Service layer

```
package com.dining.service;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.dining.data.UserRepo;
import com.dining.exceptions.ChangeUsernameException;
import com.dining.exceptions.UserNotFoundException;
import com.dining.model.User;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired UserRepo userRepo;
    @Autowired User tempUser;
    
    
    public User addUser(User user) {
        try {
            if(userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
                throw new SecurityException();
            }
            else {
                tempUser = userRepo.save(user);
                //future implementation is to add security (password)
                return tempUser;
                        
            }
        }
        
        catch(SecurityException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.printf("Username %s", user.getUsername())
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }
    
    public Optional<User> getUser(String username) {
        
        Optional <User> tempUser = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        if(tempUser.isEmpty()){
            throw new UserNotFoundException(String.format("Unable to find user: %s", username));
            
        }
        else {
            return tempUser;
        }
    
    
    }

}
```

```
package com.dining.data;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.dining.model.User;
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
    


    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

I have tried sending this JSON object as my body of my request. I believe the sql error comes from username value not being read. It shows username=? in the sql statement

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username":"Jb",
    "city": "toledo",
    "state": "NC",
    "zip": "43706",
    "peanutAll":"false",
    "eggAll":"false",
    "dairyAll":"false"
}
```

I am noticing that if I mispell the username key in my object it isn't throwing an error. It still attempts to run the sql statement but shows username=null . Here is the error stack tracing im getting

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement [Syntax error in SQL statement "select u1_0.id,u1_0.city,u1_0.dairy_all,u1_0.egg_all,u1_0.peanut_all,u1_0.state,u1_0.username,u1_0.zip from [*]user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:\nselect u1_0.id,u1_0.city,u1_0.dairy_all,u1_0.egg_all,u1_0.peanut_all,u1_0.state,u1_0.username,u1_0.zip from user u1_0 where u1_0.username=? [42001-214]] [select u1_0.id,u1_0.city,u1_0.dairy_all,u1_0.egg_all,u1_0.peanut_all,u1_0.state,u1_0.username,u1_0.zip from user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?]; SQL [select u1_0.id,u1_0.city,u1_0.dairy_all,u1_0.egg_all,u1_0.peanut_all,u1_0.state,u1_0.username,u1_0.zip from user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy120.findByUsername(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.dining.service.UserService.getUser(UserService.java:48)

Comment: Please format the stacktrace correctly

Comment: @Jens Is that better or is there another way to format it?

Answer (score 1):

is the database you use H2 or any database that has USER as a reserved keyword? From the error stack trace this is what I am suspecting. Try to rename your table to something custom, like *UserSummary*, and see if this is still reproducible.
Or you can use this in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

More about this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-jdbcsqlsyntaxerrorexception-expected-identifier).